# Update en el ultimo id registrado

Tags: php, update, postman, maxima

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que después de un `insert`, seleccionar el ultimo `numFile(id autoincrementable)` que se registro y hacer un `update` a la misma tabla pero en la columna `folio`, deberia de quedar de esta manera, siendo el numero `19` el año actual: **`EST-0013-19`**

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Tijuana');
$year = date("y");

 $select = "SELECT MAX(numFile) FROM inventory_list; ";
    $folio = [0][0];
    echo ($folio);
   $insert = 'UPDATE inventory_list set folio = "EST-00".$folio. $year where MAX(numFile)';
```

Cuando hago pruebas en postman y demás, sale que si se registro, con `echo ($folio);`  la impresión de esto da `0`

Salida desde postman.

```
 0 {
        "status": "0",
        "errorMessage": "ITEM registrado"
   }
```

Haciendo la prueba de ese update directamente el MySql

```
UPDATE inventory_list set folio = 'EST-0047-19' where MAX(numFile)
```

Sale este error:

> ## 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Como puedo hacer ese update en el ultimo id registrado? y como concatenar los valores y letreros?

Comment: no tenes ningun control de error? igual hacer esto no esta bien.. en un entorno multiusuario no podes suponer que el ultimo que hico el insert es el que va a hacer el update.. por eso es multiusuario, muchos trabajando al mismo tiempo. Esto se haria mejor usando por ejemplo un trigger. y si, no sobran puntos en ese update?

Comment: Como lo mencione realmente no estoy segura si el update en si va dentro de comillas simples y si los letreros van con doble comilla, tambien si es la manera de capturar el ultimo id, o si puedo ponerlo asi `$insert = 'UPDATE inventory_list set folio = "EST-00".$selec. $year where MAX(numFile)';` cambiar el $folio por la consulta en si.

Comment: a ver.. porque primero no pruebas la consulta en la db? ninguna de esas que estas mostrando va a andar en la base de datos.. y de ahi la transfieres a tu sistema.. esa seria la forma logica de trabajar...

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta.

Comment: y si.. no podes usar un max ahi asi como asi... no funciona asi el max

Comment: Podrias orientarme en como editar el campo folio donde numFile sea el ultimo

Comment: lo que pasa es que vos queres solucionar esto, y no leiste mi primer comentario o lo pasaste por alto queriendo arreglar esto, cuando el problema esta en otro lado. El select ese lo puedo escribir. el string en php tambien. Pero vos entendes que esto en un entorno multiusuario no funciona? si el usr 1 hace un insert, y despue entra un insert del usr 2, cuando el usr 1 haga el update, no va a tomar su registro, va a tomar el registro del usr 2.. queda claro eso?

Comment: Si queda claro, siempre hay una solución...

Comment: Si, pero no es hacer esto, a eso me refiero, salvo que tu primer insert devuelva el valor insertado. Si no, la solucion es o un SP que haga todo esto en una transaccion, o un trigger que es todavia mucho mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mas alla de los problemas que te puse en los comentarios, y que voy a repetir aca abajo, si esto ***no fuera un entorno multiusuario*** (lo resalto), podrías solucionarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$insert = "UPDATE inventory_list set folio = \"EST-00$folio$year\" where numfile = (select MAX(numFile) from inventory_list )";
```

El manual de php dice que para que las variables se expandan, el string tiene que ser de tipo ["comillas dobles"](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). y para agregar las mismas en el string, hay que escaparlas

De esta forma armas el update como corresponde, haciéndolo solo sobre el ultimo registro insertado en esa tabla.

Igual, como nota al margen, vuelvo a remarcar los problemas de esto, si el entorno fuera multiusuario:

> si el usr 1 hace un insert, y después entra un insert del usr 2,
>   cuando el usr 1 haga el update, no va a tomar su registro, va a tomar
>   el registro del usr 2.

La solución a eso es hacer un trigger en la db, o tomar el valor al mismo tiempo que se hace el insert (tal vez con un SP?)